# Convert JSON with changeable array keys to Java object

Tags: java, json, gson

I receive JSON data from web service and I would like to convert it into Java object. The ways are many, however I don't find any that could deal with **changeble array keys** that I receive in the json.

JSON example:

```
{
    "total": 2,
    "last": "AAAI9Zgh",
    "results": {
        "67701510/2/1150671": {
            "attributes": {
              "200": "11444413213123",
              "201": "Frank"     
            },
            "id": "67701510/2/1150671"
        },
       "76701410/3/1330671": {
            "attributes": {
              "200": "11666613213123",
              "201": "Mary"
            },
            "id": "76701410/3/1330671"
        }
    }
}
```

In the *results* there are 2 objects. Name of each object is an ID of the object so it is changeble. 
The method like this

> return new Gson().fromJson(json, clazz);

is not working.

I would like to reach *attributes* and *id* data in each object.

Could anyone give some method to do so?

Comment: Use a `Map<String, yourObject>` for the mapping.

Comment: Great! That works! Please open an answer so that I could "+" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you have dynamic keys in your JSON, they can be mapped as `Map<String, Object>`.

Let's say you have a class `Result` that wraps the Results attributes, you just need to use `Map<String, Result>` in your GSON mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jackson a java library and convert the JSON string to java Map.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
Map parsedJson = mapper.readValue(json,Map.class)
```

Then the parsedJson variable will be a Map containing the parsed json.

Sorry for not showing example in GSON, I am less familiar with this library.